# Running on Ubuntu for Windows IIS Server, the C code returns -1 for recv()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, iis, winsock

I have a IIS Server running on Windows 10 and the following code is getting executed from CLion IDE for C on Ubuntu. The program stuck always at recv() throwing -1 as the value.

I am able to get the response from the server using curl so I am able to reach to the server from the machine.

```
#if defined WIN32
#include <winsock.h>
#else
#define closesocket close
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 512
#define PROTOPORT 5193 
# pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
void ClearWinSock() {
#if defined WIN32
    WSACleanup();
#endif
}

void ErrorHandler(char *errorMessage) {
    printf(errorMessage);
}

int main(void) {
#if defined WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2 ,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("error at WSASturtup\n");
        return 0;
    }
#endif


    int Csocket;
    Csocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (Csocket < 0) {
        ErrorHandler("socket creation failed.\n");
        closesocket(Csocket);
        ClearWinSock();
        return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sad;
    memset(&sad, 0, sizeof(sad));
    sad.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sad.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.56"); // IP del server
    sad.sin_port = htons(443); // Server port
    // CONNESSIONE AL SERVER
    if (connect(Csocket, (struct sockaddr *) &sad, sizeof(sad)) < 0) {
        ErrorHandler("Failed to connect.\n");
        closesocket(Csocket);
        ClearWinSock();
        return 0;
    }

    char* inputString = "GET /\r\nHTTP/2\r\nHost:10.0.0.56\r\n\r\n"; 
    int stringLen = strlen(inputString); // Determina la lunghezza

    if (send(Csocket, inputString, stringLen, 0) != stringLen) {
        ErrorHandler("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
        closesocket(Csocket);
        ClearWinSock();
        return 0;
    }

    int bytesRcvd;
    int totalBytesRcvd = 0;
    char buf[BUFFERSIZE]; // buffer for data from the server
    printf("Received: "); // Setup to print the echoed string

    while (totalBytesRcvd < stringLen) {
        if ((bytesRcvd = recv(Csocket, buf, BUFFERSIZE - 1, 0)) <= 0) {
            ErrorHandler("recv() failed or connection closed prematurely");
            closesocket(Csocket);
            ClearWinSock();
            return 0;
        }
        totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd; // Keep tally of total bytes
        buf[bytesRcvd] = '\0'; // Add \0 so printf knows where to stop
        printf("%s", buf); // Print the echo buffer
    }

    closesocket(Csocket);
    ClearWinSock();
    printf("\n"); // Print a final linefeed
    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

The method recv() always returns -1. Not sure what could be a problem here.

Comment: What does errno contain? Print strerror(errno) for more info

Comment: Whenever a system call reports an error, use `perror()` to see the error message.

Comment: @BjornA. The Error says Connection Reset By Peer

Comment: @Barmar The error code is 104

Comment: You shouldn't have a newline between `GET /` and `HTTP/2`, they should be on the same line.

Comment: And `HTTP/2` should be `HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Both these changes does not have any effect on the result. @Barmar

Comment: You're connecting to port 443, that's used for SSL. You can't send a plaintext HTTP request on that port, you have to use the encryption protocol.

Comment: @Barmar .. I tossed a new http server with port 80 on the same IIS server and i am still giving the same error number. Also, the same http server is accessible over curl without any issue.

Comment: curl knows how to do SSL encryption.

Comment: Use a packet capture program like Wireshark or tcpdump to see what's actually being sent, and compare it to curl.